# VB.NET How to pass a data table from one form to another

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual studio Express 2013 and VB.NET
How do I pass a data table from one form to another.

Regards

Comment: Believe me I've been at it for days. Tried different approaches on other forums. Thank you Nate.

Comment: Mitch your presumption is wrong.

Comment: My apologies. Forgot to thank you both for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a data table from one form to another just as you would any variable. For example, you can declare it public in form1 and refer to it from form2 with the the form instance as the qualifier: `form1.dtable`. There are several other ways to handle this, such as using a class for the data table or declaring it public in a module.

Comment: Thank you xpda. Excatly what I needed.